# When is the QBPrivateChat instance created locally?

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I am new with quickblox. I have read all the examples and could create a simple chat with notifications, but there is something I do not understand.

Following the quickblox guide, it says to add the QBPrivateChatManagerListener which callback methods has 2 parameters

**(final QBPrivateChat privateChat, final boolean createdLocally)**

It is called when chat is created by sending first message, but I cannot see how to create it locally without the need to receive a first message. Something like:

**QBPrivateChatManager.createChat()**

Maybe I do not understand correctly the chat flow?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that creates the chat manually and locally:

```
privateChatManager.createChat(opponentId, privateChatMessageListener);
```